# Temporary Variable with aggregate field and group by doesn't work in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get cumulative value of a column using temporary variable.

```
SELECT sum(price), @temp := @temp + sum(price) AS cumulative_price  FROM `table`, (SELECT @temp := 0) B GROUP BY item
```

It work when there is no group by and aggregate field. However, when there is group by field, value of cumulative_price  is same as sum(price), which is not a expected.

What could be the reason of this inconsistency?

Comment: What makes you say it's an inconsistency?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because same query works when there is no group by and aggregate field.

Comment: That seems _highly_ "consistent" to me! :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can you enlighten me with the reason and possible solution of this issue. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: You haven't said what the issue is. What are you trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: What i am trying to accomplish is temp += sum(price)  . Value of temp should increase with every record processed.

Comment: That's not what you're trying to accomplish; that's _how_ you think you can accomplish it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78238/discussion-between-user2779912-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Answer (score 0):

It should not work. According to [Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

> In a SELECT statement, each select expression is evaluated only when
>   sent to the client. This means that in a HAVING, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY
>   clause, referring to a variable that is assigned a value in the select
>   expression list does not work as expected:

```
mysql> SELECT (@aa:=id) AS a, (@aa+3) AS b FROM tbl_name HAVING b=5;
```

> The reference to b in the HAVING clause refers to an alias for an
>   expression in the select list that uses @aa. This does not work as
>   expected: @aa contains the value of id from the previous selected row,
>   not from the current row.

So when you define a variable it will work for current row not set of rows